# Slide menu with NavigationWindow

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

I have an application that uses NavigationWindow (on iOS) as it's main container. Also the app has a slide menu. How can I organize switching NavigationWindow's first window by selecting different menu options (which correspond to different first screens in navigation windows chain)?

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple windows that are loaded from a custom side menu, which could be a window with a simple tableView that is animated in on a NavigationButton click your best bet is to create module that can be used on every window within the application.

This module can then have custom navigation events allowing for opening and closing the windows and this managing the devices resources so you manage the memory correctly avoiding the application to eventually topple over.

One correct method is to use an array that is populated everytime a Window is opened, then in your slideMenu on the corresponding click event on for the desired window it can call the function to load the required window.

eg.

```
/* Window navigation module */

var openWin = null,
    prevWin = null,
    windowArray = [];


function windowNavigation(param) {
    // add to the window array
    windowArray.push(param);

    // Move the open window reference to the previous window
    prevWin = openWin;
    openWin = param;

    // Open the new window reference
    openWin.open();

    // Close the previous window to mangage the applications memory.
    if (prevWin) {
        prevWin.close();
        prevWin = null;
    }
}
```